# unity interception auto config in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, unity-interception

I'm trying to get interception working in vb.net since my work only allows that.
I've never encountered a lambda that has this If.something syntax before.

```
        scan.Include(If.Implements<IBusinessService>, (x, y) =>
        {
            if (x.IsClass)
                y.Configure<Interception>().
                    SetDefaultInterceptorFor(x,
                                            new VirtualMethodInterceptor
                                                ());
        })
```

How does this look in vb.net? What is this syntax called in case I need to google this in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not part of the language, or the standard library.  It's just a custom method some developer wrote, or it's a part of a 3rd party library.  We could theorize, based on the name and context, how it might be implemented, but they would only be guesses.

Comment: Yea, the problem is that I was looking at unity auto register instead of unity config. I dug into the auto registration code, and found the static class and how it was implemented. Once I changed the reference everything worked fine.